# Как разово отменить выполнение события

Tags: c#, winforms

Задача связать 2 способа задания размера окна

Есть **NumericUpDown** в котором я меняю размер окна, в зависимости от **Value**.

Есть обработчик событий **pictureBox_ClientSizeChanged**, в котором я меняю **NumericUpDown.Value** в зависимости от размера окна

Соответственно, лишний вызов события. Меняю значение окна через **Value** -> меняется размер окна -> вызывается **pictureBox_ClientSizeChanged**, и из-за этого повторного вызова переменная обрабатывается 2 раза, и оказывается неверной

Что нужно прописать в **numericUpDown_ValueChanged**, чтобы не вызывалось событие изменения окна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заведите флаг и выставляйте его в нужный момент:

```
bool flag = false;

private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flag) return;
    flag = true;
    Width = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    flag = false;
}

private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (flag) return;
    flag = true;
    numericUpDown1.Value = Width;
    flag = false;
}
```